# Copying a working chart from a spreadsheet to a document results with "Not enough columns given to draw this requested chart"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google spreadsheet that contains charts which are properly displayed. When I am using a GAS to copy these charts to a Google document some of the charts are properly displayed in the document while others (which are displayed properly in the spreadsheet) are displaying the message "Not enough columns given to draw this requested chart" in red.

Since these are working charts I am not sure why I get this message. Is there a workaround to this problem or a known issue?

Any advise will help.

Thx!

Comment: Add some code what you are working to copy the charts. Also attach a sample sheet if you can, so it will be easy to analyze.

Comment: Took me a while to prepare a version I can share. Please copy the following files. The script is embedded within the excel sheet. You just have to change the id of the template to the doc one you copied and run the script. Spreadsheet and script: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AphsvceI4elpdG52bVJUdkpGdWxqWkRTajhNNUxmU0E. Template doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jwnAlOUGH83BgHpgkLZgNqW0HzNvPHpBpObndPzVbHU. Appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by creating a duplicate chart and then deleting the old one. It now works. Weird...